# why does the python version change when i run it from different locations?

Tags: python, anaconda

When i run the python compiler from ...Anaconda2>python i get python version 2.7.11. But when i run the python compiler from ...Anaconda2/Lib>python i get python version 3.5.1.

Not sure whats happening:

```
C:\Anaconda2>python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 14:26:21) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> exit()

C:\Anaconda2>cd lib

C:\Anaconda2\Lib>python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You've installed one version in one directory, and installed another in the other. No?

Comment: This seems to be more about how your command interpreter finds an executable than it is about Python.

Comment: Do a `which python` and you will see where python is running from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `python` in cmd Windows at first search for `python.exe` in current directory. If you stay in `C:\Anaconda2` it run python2 from Anaconda2 installation. When you execute `python` from `C:\Anaconda2\lib` Windows could not find it in the current folder, looks into `PATH` environment variable and found another `python` from another Anaconda installation.